# Will python accept - (dash) as a filename to `open()` to write to stdout?

Tags: python, file, stdout

I am working with a Python script that accepts an outfile as an argument. It uses `open(outfile, "w")` to open and write to that file.

A common convention in Linux is to use `-` (dash) to write to stdout. [It is a common convention but not standard nor part of a shell.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename)

Can I pass `-` as the outfile name so that Pythons `open` writes to stdout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the standard library [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) does not translate the filename `'-'` into `stdin` or `stdout`.  It is just an *ordinary filename*, so `open("-", "w")` will write to a file in the current working directory named `-`.

You have to explicitly test for that value and so return `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout` (depending on what you needed to read from or write to), instead of opening a file.

E.g. the [`click` command-line interface library](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/), which [supports using `-` as a filename on the command line](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/arguments/#file-arguments), explicitly tests for a `'-'` filename in their [`open_stream()` implementation](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/6944450c5331f2d652d342650b6d9b3b52404baa/click/_compat.py#L470-L515):

```
if filename == '-':
    if any(m in mode for m in ['w', 'a', 'x']):
        if 'b' in mode:
            return get_binary_stdout(), False
        return get_text_stdout(encoding=encoding, errors=errors), False
    if 'b' in mode:
        return get_binary_stdin(), False
    return get_text_stdin(encoding=encoding, errors=errors), False
```

`open()` does accept [file handles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), so you can pass in `0` for standard input, or `1` for standard output:

```
>>> inp = open(0)
>>> inp
<_io.TextIOWrapper name=0 mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> inp.read(1)  # read 1 character from stdin, I entered 'a'
a
'a'
>>> outp = open(1, 'w')
>>> outp
<_io.TextIOWrapper name=1 mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> outp.write("foo!")  # line buffered, no newline written so not visible yet
4
>>> outp.flush()  # flush the buffer
foo!>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's depend on how you retrieve commandline arguments.
With sys.argv, argparse or OptionParser modules, yes you can.
It mean that you can retrieve '-'.
But it's up to you to open stdout in this case.

Comment: The script I have uses `OptionParser` https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html

Answer (score -1):

You should test to be sure, but according to Python docs:

> open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None,
> newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
>
> *file* is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or relative
> to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or an
> integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped. (If a file
> descriptor is given, it is closed when the returned I/O object is
> closed, unless closefd is set to False.)
>
> A path-like object is an object representing a file system path. A
> path-like object is either a str or bytes object representing a path,
> or an object implementing the os.PathLike protocol. An object that
> supports the os.PathLike protocol can be converted to a str or bytes
> file system path by calling the os.fspath() function; os.fsdecode()
> and os.fsencode() can be used to guarantee a str or bytes result
> instead, respectively. Introduced by PEP 519.

So yes, it should work.

Plase refeer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open and https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object for more information.

Comment: I tried it and ended up with a file literally named `-` (dash) `-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 232M Nov 20 15:25 -` . I think that `sys.stdout` is a file-like object but I don't think I can pass it as an argument.

Comment: This doesn't say **anything** about whether or not it is supported. It is not supported, because `-` is not a valid filename.

Comment: Thank you guys for the explanation, I haven't sure about it too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ...eh? `-` is a perfectly valid filename on UNIX (evaluating to a file named `-` in the current directory, though, whereas the OP is asking if they can use that name to get a handle on stdout; afaict your answer is the only correct and on-point one here, so my quibble is only with the comment).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I was being imprecise. It is a valid filename but is not meant to be used as one. It’s a symbiotic name here.

Answer (score -2):

Tested on linux mint 19 (python 3.6) and there seems to be no problem. The characters you should avoid in filenames though are:

> \ / : * ? " < > |

Some of them actually work on linux but why would you sacrifice portability?

Comment: The OP doesn't want to open a file whose name is a dash, they want to open stdout (as many tools on UNIX treat a single dash as a reference to the existing stdin or stdout FD, depending on whether the open is for read or write). The advice about filenames is a complete non-sequitur.

Comment: I've re-read the OP's post, and it's entirely clear that they're asking if `open('-', 'w')` opens stdout, *not* if it can be used to open a file named `-`.

Comment: BTW, *every* character other than `/` and the NUL character is valid in filenames on conventional Unixlike systems (and of course `/` is valid in fully-qualified paths, so it could be accurately said that NUL is the only invalid character in filenames on UNIX). That's beside the point, though, that the OP wasn't asking about valid filenames at all, but was asking if they need special handling to make a `-` passed to their script as a filename resolve to `sys.stdin` or `sys.stdout` as appropriate; their comments on other answers and their choice of accepted answer make this even more clear.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that was fast. Sorry, I'd deleted my earlier comment and it's only after the browser refresh that I realised you'd answered.